# How to call a function on append-icon click in Vuetify.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need the `append-icon="close"` to call `@click="clearSearch()"`

Right now I'm implementing it with a dedicated button:

```html
<v-text-field 
  v-model="search" 
  class="search" 
  label="search" 
  prepend-icon="search" 
  append-icon="close">
</v-text-field>    
                                
<v-btn @click="clearSearch()"></v-btn>
```

---

- I've tried adding `append-icon-cb="clearSearch()"` but it doesn't work and I don't know why
- I've also tried simply using `clearable`, it clears the input but all the elements stay "filtered". I don't know how `clearable` works but my `clearSearch()` method simply does: `clearSearch() {this.search = ""}` and it works, that's why I use the custom **clear input** method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Solved it, here's the solution:

To avoid that problem you should bind the attribute with `:` symbol:

`:append-icon-cb="clearSearch"`

And don't put `()` otherwise it will not work (as @Traxo mentioned)

Answer (score 47):

Use `@click:append="clearSearch"`, `:append-icon-cb` is deprecated. ([Source](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5565))

Answer (score 3):

This changed though:
For append icons e.g
`append-icon="mdi-magnify-plus-outline"`,
you just do  `@click:append="zoomIn"`.

But for append outer icons like `append-outer-icon="mdi-plus-circle-outline"`,`
you must add the word append i.e

```
 @click:append-outer="addMore"
```

therefore, this will work with Vue2

```html
<v-text-field
  solo
  append-outer-icon="mdi-plus-circle-outline"
  @click:append-outer="addMore"
>
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: for inner icons this would be @click:append-inner="addMore"

Answer (score 2):

I think it should work if you remove `()`, because with `()` included, you immediately just call function once.

Edit: don't forget colon `:`

So:

```
:append-icon-cb="clearSearch"
```

Comment: Good call, but it didn't solve the problem, I got `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "appendIconCb". Expected Function, got String.` But then I added `:` symbol and it worked. Thanks for the answer, it helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just Change `:append-icon-cb="() => (e1 = !e1)"` to `@click:append="() => (e1 = !e1)"` and this will work perfectly and remove the warning too...